# Simple C++ Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have plenty of previous experience with linked lists in Java, but I seem to have confused myself with this simple attempt in C++. I am getting a segmentation fault at runtime, which from what I understand has to do with assigning a null pointer, but I am at a loss for a solution.

Edit: Thank you all for the very helpful responses. The code is now working, but trying to use

```
delete p;
```

at the end of linkedList::addNode results in a segmentation fault at runtime. Just curious if anyone knew why that is?

Here is my updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
    Node * next;
    Node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
        }
    Node(int x, Node * y){
        data = x; 
        next = y;
        }
    };


class linkedList{
Node *head;
public:
    linkedList(){
        head = NULL;
        }
    void addNode(int value){
        Node *p;
        if(head == NULL)
            head = new Node (value, NULL);
        else{
            p=head;
            while(p->next !=NULL)
                p=p->next;
            p->next = new Node (value, NULL);
            }
        }
    void print(){
        Node * p;
        p = head;
        while(p != NULL){
            cout << p->data << "\n";
            p = p->next;
            }
        }
};


int main(void){
linkedList test;
test.addNode(4);
test.addNode(76);
test.addNode(12);
test.print();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: The segmentation fault arises because as soon as you delete an object, you aren't allowed to reference it anymore. It doesn't make any sense to delete the node right after you add it (and there is now a pointer to it).

Comment: Why are you deleting p in print()?

Comment: My mistake, I was initially a little confused about where to use delete, but I think I understand now.

Comment: you've edited the question in such a way that it can't be compared with the answers given

Answer (score 6):

First, in `linkedList::addNode` method, you have the construction `if (head = NULL)`, which will wind up *assigning* to `head`; you want the `==` operator.

Second, about the line:

```
head = &(Node (value, NULL));
```

For somewhat unintuitive reasons, this won't work. You'll get a reference to a `Node`, but that node will go out of scope as soon as the method ends, and attempts to reference it will lead to a segmentation fault. You need to use the `new` operator (same with the other similar line):

```
head = new Node(value, NULL);
```

If you add a method for removing a node, make sure to `delete` the node then—it won't get automatically garbage-collected like it will in Java.

> > **Sidebar:** Think of what happens like this: when you do `Node(value, NULL)`, you're using a temporary variable that's declared like this:
> >
> > ```
> > Node hiddenTempNode(value, NULL);
> > ```
> >
> > This doesn't allocate space for an object anywhere except on the stack—it's very similar to allocating space for an `int` and a `Node *` on the stack as separate variables. As a result, as soon as you leave the method, the object disappears and the pointer to it will do weird things when used.

Third, beware: you may want to set `next = NULL` in your single-parameter constructor, to ensure that it always has a value. Similarly for your default constructor.

Fourth: your `linkedList::print` method is looping until `p->next` is `NULL` and printing the value of `p->next`; those occurrences of `p->next` should probably be changed to just `p` if you want to get the first and last items.

Answer (score 3):

you are taking the address of variables on the stack

```
head = &(Node (value, NULL));
```

should be changed to

```
head = new Node(value, NULL);
```

same for the p->next code.  Then you will want to delete these nodes in your destructor.

As for the printing try

```
while(p != NULL)
{
   cout << p->data << "\n";
   p = p->next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters

```
if(head = NULL)
```

is an assignment, not a check for equality.  Change it to

```
if(head == NULL)
```

Secondly,

```
head = &(Node (value, NULL));
```

Doesn't make sense* change this to

```
head = new Node (value, NULL);
```

*this actually creates a temporary object, gives you the address, then destroys that newly created object.

Thirdly,

```
Node(int x) { data = x; }
```

Leave `next` without a value, change this line to

```
Node(int x) { data = x; next = NULL; }
```

Comment: Oh my what a glaring omission :(, however I am now faced with a repeated printing of 134514880

Comment: Check all of the other answers, then edit your first post to show your current code.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating space for nodes on stack and grabbing its address, which will go away as soon as the block ends and consequently, the address will be rendered invalid. You should allocate nodes using `new` operator on the heap instead:

```
Node* node = new Node(value, NULL);
```

You should free everything you allocate on the heap as soon as you don't need it to prevent memory leak:

```
delete node;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating memory.You should use new to allocate it.

One more error  in if(head = NULL) , it should be if(head == NULL)

```
void addNode(int value){
            Node *p;
            if(head == NULL)
                    head =  new Node (value, NULL);
            else{
                    p=head;
                    while(p->next !=NULL)
                            p=p->next;
                    p->next = new Node (value, NULL);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add two issues that were not mentioned, yet:

- when you 'new' objects, you must 'delete' them at some point.
- all three of your constructors should initialize both member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete statement is not actually doing any cleanup. By the time you call it p==null. If you want to cleanup the list, you will need to implement a separate method to iterate through, and delete each and every node.

Something like this:

```
void ClearList ()
{
    Node * c = head;
    Node * n;

    while (c != NULL)
    {
        n = c->next;
        delete c;
        c = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so just setting head = NULL would leave all the remaining nodes occupying memory then?

Answer (score 0):

> The code is now working, but trying to
>   use
>
> `delete p;`
>
> at the end of linkedList::addNode
>   results in a segmentation fault at
>   runtime. Just curious if anyone knew
>   why that is?

Well this is an issue because the purpose of the add node function was to dynamically allocate a new node at the end of the LinkedList. So you do that correctly, now by putting 'delete p;' you are deleting the newly added node (something I imagine you don't actually want). However, to answer your question which is why this causes a segmentation fault:

You add a node, you tell head to point to this new node. Now you delete this new node without telling head that it should once again point to NULL. Thus next time you add a node, or try to print your list, it will immediately attempt to look at what head is pointing to, which is in fact released (deleted) memory, kaboom?

The correct (or at least one correct) usage of delete in your list is in a destructor, remember in C++ we always want to clean up the dynamic memory that we have allocated, your destructor might look like:

```
~linkedList()
{
    Node* p = head;
    while ( p!=NULL )
    {
        Node* nextNode = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = nextNode;
    }
}
```

By using a destructor like this you guarantee that your linkedList will be cleaned up appropriately when it goes out of scope, or is deleted.

Answer (score -2):

Solution: Don't implement your own linked list. Use the one supplied by the standard library.

Comment: I think it's a good exercise to implement one yourself at least a couple times.

Comment: In some languages, yes. In C++, what is it going to teach you? IF it seems to work, but still contains a number of bugs you hadn't spotted, has that made you a better programmer? Writing code that seems to work in C++ is easy. Writing code that is actually correct is painfully hard. Unless you've got some way to ensure that you're actually achieving the latter, this exercise won't teach you anything.